# TypeError: expected a single-segment buffer object

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, hough-transform

I am trying to use OpenCV and Python to detect circular shapes in a webcam capture. Im using a Hough transform for the circle detection, which in it self took several hours for me to figure out (and which I still am unsure if I really have). Anyways, my current problem lies in using the correct type of objects in different function calls. I have posted my code below for reference. When I run this code i get the following error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv.Canny(gray, edges, 50, 200, 3)
TypeError: expected a single-segment buffer object`

What does this mean? I have tried to look around different threads to figure this oout, but I can't seem to find a good explanation.

I am new to OpenCV and would really appreciate any simple elaboration on what could be the cause my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
import cv
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Starting camera capture
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

    #Allocating grayscale- and edge-images
    gray = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 1)
    edges = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img), 8, 1)

    #Transforming frame to grayscale image
    cv.CvtColor(img, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

    #Preprocessing and smoothing
    cv.Erode(gray, gray, None, 2)
    cv.Dilate(gray, gray, None, 2)
    cv.Smooth(gray, gray, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9)

    #Edge detection (I believe this is where the exception is thrown)
    cv.Canny(gray, edges, 50, 200, 3)

    #Transforming original frame and grayscale image to numpy arrays
    img = np.asarray(img[:,:])
    gray = np.asarray(gray[:,:])

    #Detecting circles and drawing them 
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,100,30,5,20)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1)  # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)     # draw the center of the circle

    #Transforming original frame back to iplimage format for showing
    img = cv.fromarray(img)

    #Showing image and edge image
    cv.ShowImage("Camera", img)
    cv.ShowImage("Edges",edges)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete answer, but the error means that the function `cv.Canny()` is expecting one of its first two arguments to be a "single-segment buffer", which is an obscure name to mean "a piece of memory that is contiguous".  It might mean that one of the arguments should actually be just a string, for example.  It might also mean that it's ok to pass in images created with `cv.CreateImage()` but only as long as there is no padding on the lines (if there is padding, it can't be represented as a single contiguous piece of memory).  Try with an image width that is a multiple of some power of 2, e.g. a multiple of 16.